# Book: main character dreams of evolving from lower life forms while he is in cold sleep

Tags: story-identification, books

I can't remember a lot of details other than a scene where the main character is dreaming about being a trilobite who has discovered that he can eat well if he stays close to a large predatory mollusk and collect food it misses.  He gets too close, though, and the mollusk starts eating him.

He is aware that he is being eaten, but keeps eating himself (perhaps literally as the mollusk is a messy eater) as hunger is his only driving force.

These dreams occur while the main character is in cold sleep on a space ship. He is not supposed to be dreaming at all, but every time he goes under, he dreams that he has evolved to a newer life form.

Comment: _[Beyond the Blue Event Horizon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beyond_the_Blue_Event_Horizon)_ has something like this, but it's a female character having the experience.

Answer (score 6):

This looks to be James White's "[The Dream Millennium](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?2054)" as serialized in *Galaxy* magazine from October to December of 1973 (below excerpt from the [December 1973 edition of *Galazy* magazine](https://archive.org/details/Galaxy_v34n03_1973-12)):

> JOHN DEVLIN is awakened from
> cold sleep by ship’s computerized
> system and told he’s seventy-five
> years into mission: man’s first attempt to colonize a star system other
> than his own. He is computer-instructed to check ship’s systems,
> then his own voluntary /involuntary
> bodily functions, circulation, sensorium, speech organ and memory. His
> period of awakening is for one hour.
> During this time he is to speak,
> exercise and try to remember his
> cold-sleep dream. In his dream he
> was a primitive, ocean-dwelling life
> form, inordinately hungry -and was
> himself eaten by a carnivorous cephalopod while eating a trilobite.

> His second awakening comes 282
> years into mission. His instructions
> are as before, but in addition he’s
> told to go to the ship's control center
> to evaluate target system three. The
> ship’s computer had bypassed the
> first two target star systems as unsuitable for human colonization.

> Number 3 is a perfect, Earth-type
> planet, unpolluted and verdant-but
> is entering Roche’s limit and will
> soon break up to become a ring
> system around its primary . DEVLIN
> rules no landing, obediently remembers last cold-sleep dream: in it he
> was an enormous brontosaurus and
> was killed by a small, carnivorous
> allosaurus.

Found with search terms of *"cold sleep" trilobite* on Google Books, and then searches on the text excerpts I found from there.

Comment: If so, it's also the answer to https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/146612/ as well as a few dupes.

Comment: This is indeed James White's "The Dream Millennium" and does have multiple duplicates.