# Novel about a crew member of a spaceship having hibernation nightmares

Tags: story-identification, novel

I read a novel from the 1970s about a crew on a ship who are in hibernation.  The story mostly deals with one crew member.  He has very disturbing dreams during his sleep periods.  Such things as being a fish, and being eaten alive by a bigger fish.  He can feel, in the dream, all the pain of being chewed.  He has waking periods to think about the dreams, and having to face the inevitability of going back into hibernation.  I cannot remember the title or author, and that is what I am seeking.

Comment: Is it the story where he hides under his blanket to make the terrors go away?

Comment: I don't remember that as part of the story. I don't think so.

Comment: Your question has been closed as a Duplicate. Please note that that does not mean it's a bad question and there's no penalty to you. It's just bookkeeping to indicate it's been answered before.

Comment: My apologies.  I guess I missed it.  I'll be more vigilant in future.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As per [Looking for a (short?) story about a cryo ship looking for habitable planets](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/146612/looking-for-a-short-story-about-a-cryo-ship-looking-for-habitable-planets), this may be *[The Dream Millennium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Dream_Millennium)* by James White, 1974.

> John Devlin, a 26-year-old medical doctor, is the captain of a sleeper ship built to colonize planets in other solar systems. The spacecraft's trajectory is such that it will make passes of eleven stars thought to have a good chance of supporting habitable planets, over the course of about a thousand years. Most of the starship's systems are automated, so Devlin does not have to do much maintenance, but he is required to look at potential planets for colonization and solve problems as they arise. Except for being awoken at long intervals to eat, exercise, and perform his duties as captain, Devlin spends all of his time in hibernation, during which he dreams the entire lives of people and other creatures that lived and died on Earth in the past.

Comment: That sounds like it.  Thanks so much!